# Why doesn't my timer thread run in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, time, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am making a simple project to learn about threading and this is my code:

```
import time
import threading

x = 0

def printfunction():
    while x == 0:
        print("process running")


def timer(delay):
    while True:
        time.sleep(delay)
        break
    x = 1
    return x

t1 = threading.Thread(target = timer,args=[3])
t2 = threading.Thread(target = printfunction)

t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

It is supposed to just print out `process running` in the console for three seconds but it never stops printing. The console shows me no errors and I have tried shortening the time to see if I wasn't waiting long enough but it still doesn't work. Then I tried to delete the `t1.join()`and `t2.join()`but I still have no luck and the program continues running.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
global x
```

to the top of `timer()`. As is, because `timer()` assigns to `x`, `x` is considered to be local to `timer()`, and its `x = 1` has no effect on the module-level variable also named `x`.  The global `x` remains 0 forever, so the `while x == 0:` in `printfunction()` always succeeds.  It really has nothing to do with threading :-)

Comment: Thank you so much!